# multiple search option in laravel model with join

Tags: laravel

i want to create a multiple search option but it gives me error when i try to search

[image]

this is my code by the way

Controller

```
    $leaves =  DB::table('leaves_admin')
                ->join('users','users.rec_id', '=', 'leaves_admin.rec_id')
                ->select('leaves_admin.*','users.role_name','users.avatar')
                ->get();

    $userList = DB::table('users')->get();

    // search by name
    $search = request('name');
    
        $leaves = LeaveAdmin::join('users','users.rec_id','=', 'leaves_admin.rec_id')
                ->select('leaves_admin.*','users.avatar')
                -> where('leaves_admin.name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
                ->get();
                
    // search by status
    $search = request('status');
    
        $leaves = LeaveAdmin::join('users','users.rec_id','=', 'leaves_admin.rec_id')
                ->select('leaves_admin.*','users.avatar')
                -> where('leaves_admin.status','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
                ->get();
    
    
    return view('Leave.leaves', compact('leaves'));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your code that you are looking for a solution for multiple filters and I am assuming that all columns are present in the same Query, so I will promote that solution for you.

```
$name = (request('name')) ? request('name') :'';
$status = (request('status')) ? request('status') :'';

$query = DB::table('leaves_admin')
      ->join('users','users.rec_id', '=', 'leaves_admin.rec_id')
      ->select('leaves_admin.*','users.role_name','users.avatar');


    if(!empty($name) && !empty($status) ) {
        $query->where('leaves_admin.name','LIKE','%'.$name.'%');
        $query->where('leaves_admin.status','LIKE','%'.$status.'%');

    }elseif (!empty($name)) {
         $query->where('leaves_admin.name','LIKE','%'.$name.'%');
    }elseif (!empty($status)) {
         $query->where('leaves_admin.status','LIKE','%'.$status.'%');
    }

  $leaves =  $query->get()->toArray();
return view('Leave.leaves', compact('leaves'));
```

Comment: i follow your code and the status search is working but when I search using the name input, it gives me no result.

Comment: @Jay-arCristobal I put conditions based on values come but you have to manipulate this according to your need , please confirm that your name parameter have values or not ?